# How do I move a list to the top of the page in Google Sites?

Tags: google-classic-sites

I have created a page using the built-in List template in Google Sites. However, the list appears after all the other text. How can I move the list to the top of the page?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do this is as follows:

1. Copy the contents of the list onto your computer's clipboard. **You need to do this *first*, as the list isn't stored in the revision history, and will be permanently deleted!**
2. Change the template used for the page to Web Page.
3. Edit the page (press the 'e' key to edit it)
4. Paste the list from your computer's clipboard into the page, where you want it to be.
5. Go to the row containing the words "sort", and from the Table menu in Google Sites, select Delete Row.
6. Save the page.

It now won't be a "proper List" as before unfortunately, so you won't be able to add items directly from the page - you'll have to go in and edit the page in order to add items to the list.